# How can html content be retrieved using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

in jquery, the .html() method works.

When i try the same in my angular app inside ng-repeat, i get nothing.

Advice?

```
$(".recentChats").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).html();
    $scope.htmlContent = value;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AngularJS [$event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-).

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lYCGbzLtEJo5G4la2tkZ?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="clickMe($event)">
    This is test content.
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.clickMe = function($event){
    console.log($event.currentTarget);
    console.log($event.currentTarget.innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you want to use jQuery to obtain or change something from the DOM, you should use a directive's `link` function.

```
    .directive('clickDirective', function () {
        return function (scope, elem) {
            elem.on('click', function () {
                var value = elem.html();
                scope.htmlContent = value;
            });
        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" click-directive>Do Something {{ thing.name }}</div>
```